# LeDavid Mizmor in Shavout morning

Tags: minhag, shavuos

Following [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125777/why-do-we-say-ledavid-mizmor-while-returning-the-torah-at-mincha-on-shabbat) question. The answer for why saying in Shabbat morning, Mizmor Ledavid (Ashkenaz, Nosah Sfard) and on a regular day and on Yom Tov that is not Shabbat, LeDavid Mizmor is that on Shabbat morning the Torah was given. My question is why in Shavout morning - the exact time when the Torah was given we say LeDavid Mizmor and not Mizmor Ledavid?